# ASP.NET MVC routing: 2 route for same page, how to give same url rendered?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I generate some url for a list, and when the id match as certain string, i d like to call another route than the default "article" one
i ve managed to that.
I ve got 3 routes, all working.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name:="ArticleToPage",
            url:="article-MySecondPage",
            defaults:=New With {.Controller = "MySecondPage", .Action = "MySecondPage"}
         )
    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="MySecondPage",
        url:="MySecondPage",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "MySecondPage", .action = "MySecondPage"}
    )

routes.MapRoute(
                name:="Article",
                url:="article-{id}",
                defaults:=New With {.Controller = "Page", .Action = "Article", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
             )
```

That s work s just fine, rerouting me exactly where i want.

But is there a way to call the route "MySecondPage" instead of "AticleToPage", in order to have the right url?
i tried to specify route the action and several things but i m getting nowhere.. DO you know a way??

**EDIT**

I might not have been clear up there

i have 2 url linked to those routes sending me to the same page :

```
Site/MySecondPage
Site/Article-MySecondPage
```

When i call "Site/Article-MySecondPage" i d like it to actually reroute to my "MySecondPage" route, or convert the url within the route call (but i don t think that s possible) to "Site/MySecondPage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your URLs:

```
Site/MySecondPage
Site/Article-MySecondPage
```

should be working. That is, when you call each of these URLs, your application should be running the action `MySecondPage` in a controller named `MySecondPageController`.

If what you want is to *generate* a URL with the second URL, you need to use `@Html.RouteLink` rather than `@Html.ActionLink` so you can pass the name of the route to match.

```
@Html.RouteLink(
    linkText:= "My Second Page 1", 
    routeName:= "ArticleToPage", 
    routeValues:= New With {.Controller = "MySecondPage", .Action = "MySecondPage"})
@Html.RouteLink(
    linkText:= "My Second Page 2", 
    routeName:= "MySecondPage", 
    routeValues:= New With {.Controller = "MySecondPage", .Action = "MySecondPage"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Routes will be called in the order how they are, so "ArticleToPage" will always be called before "MySecondPage".

Comment: i ve tried that already, but it doesn t work since the url i want to change match the "ArticleToPage"

Comment: but in both routes you call the same controller and action, without any change, or extra attribute

Comment: also the url must be like the url you want. example
`routes.MapRoute(
                name:="Article",
                url:="{controller}/{action}-{id}",
                defaults:=New {Controller = "Page", Action = "Article", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
             );`